# Overflowed with so many Outlook Push notification subscription

Tags: node.js, api, outlook, push-notification

Due to some bug in the code the user has continuously subscribed numerous times Outlook Push Notifications through API. Now getting a hell lot of webhook calls on the callback Url again and again in our Nodejs system. Is there any possible solutions to unsubscribe to all these notifs in one go by api or any means

Comment: You might want to take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations#DeleteSub , just write a loop and delete that subscription

Comment: Yes i am already using this but the issue is in a loop when it reaches a certain limit the MS rejects the delete requests and tells to try again after few minutes, that's where i am unable to delete all those recurring subscriptions within the loop

Comment: Then you just need to time your loop, mate. Create a cron job to call the API after certain interval. There is no much else you can do because that's a Microsoft built-in security policy.

Comment: Yeah thats the only possible thing i am trying to do as well. Thanks BTW @JoelChu